# SQL Query Optimization - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a query such as the one below. This query I have currently works, but I am curious if there is a better implementation. This will be placed inside of a much larger script so I want to ensure it runs as fast as possible.

```
        CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT DISTINCT x.User_Index
                FROM ActiveUser_s
                INNER JOIN Entity_s
                ON ActiveEntity_s.Entity_Index = Entity_s.Entity_Index
                INNER JOIN x
                ON Entity_s.User_Index = x.User_Index
                WHERE ActiveUser_s.Active = 1 AND Entity_s.User_Index = x.User_Index
                )
                then 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS [Is Real]
```

Comment: If you care about performance, start by upgrading to a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: Your subquery doesn't appear to be correlated (but can't really know from just a fragment of a complete query) so perhaps an outer join might be an alternative. Replace `SELECT DISTINCT x.User_Index`  with `SELECT *` since EXISTS only cares about the presence of rows and not the content - DISTINCT does nothing useful in this context. But you can't really tune a code snippet by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your script fragment provides little informations for a solution "I want to ensure it runs as fast as possible."

Some advice:

- do not use DISTINCT, use SELECT x.User_Index ....
- create indexes for database tables ActiveUser_s, Entity_s and x